# remove css :hover attribute with jquery

Tags: jquery

Lets say I have

```
<style>
    #container:hover{background:red}
</style>
<div id="container"><input type="submit"></div>
```

When I hover on submit, `#container` is still red. Can I  remove that :hover on input mouseover with jquery? I do not want to change bg `$('#container').css('backgroundColor','color')`, I need something like  `$('#container').removeAttr('hover')`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Unfortunately it is impossible to manage CSS pseudo-classes with jQuery.

I'd suggest you to manipulate classes, as follows:

```
<style>
    .red:hover{background:red}
</style>

<div id="container" class="red"><input type="submit"></div>

<script>
    $("#container").removeClass("red");
</script>
```

Comment: sorry not an option, I need to back #container to unhover state

Comment: But what's the problem in using combination: `#container.red:hover { background: red; }`?

Answer (score 6):

You can't remove pseudo-class rules, but you can override them with event bindings:

```
$("#container").on('mouseover', function () {
   $(this).css('background', 'blue');
}).on('mouseout', function () {
   $(this).css('background', whateverItIsNormally);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be a bit convoluted and could certainly use optimization, but you could use a combination of things posted so far:

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/psyon001/Vcnvz/2/

```
<style>
    .red{background:red;}
</style>

<div id="container"><input type="submit"></div>

<script>
$('#container').on({
    'mouseenter' : function(){
        $(this).addClass('red');
    },
    'mouseleave' : function(){
        $(this).removeClass('red');
    }
});
$('#container').find('input').on({
    'mouseenter' : function(){
        $('#container').removeClass('red');
    },
    'mouseleave' : function(){
        $('#container').addClass('red');
    }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your browser pointer-events:none might help

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Answer (score 1):

We can Override CSS hover effect with the help of css and Jquery

```
$('div').hover(function(){ $(this).addClass('nohover');})

In CSS Add Class .nohover
.nohover {
pointer-events:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I applied this:

```
element.click(function(){
  element.hover(
    function(){
     element.css('background-color', '');
     element.css('color', '');
  },
    function(){
     element.css('background-color', '');
     element.css('color', '');
  });
});
```

And it seemed to work in removing the hover properties while retaining the original CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is better

```
<style>
    .red:hover { background-color:red; }
</style>
<!-- by default is On-->
<div class="box red"></div>
<script>
    $('.box').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('red');
    });
</script>
```