# Remove a hover class from a checkbox once clicked

Tags: html, css, checkbox, hover

I am trying to remove a hover class applied to a checkbox via CSS once the box has been clicked.
Does anyone know how to do this?

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sa9fe/

The checkbox code is:

```
    <div>
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1-1" class="regular-checkbox flaticon-boxing3" />
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1-2" class="regular-checkbox" />
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1-3" class="regular-checkbox" />
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1-4" class="regular-checkbox" />
    </div>
```

And the CSS for the checkbox are as follows:

```
.regular-checkbox {
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
align: center;
color: #39c;
width: 140px;
height: 140px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
background-color: #fff;
border: solid 1px #ccc;
-webkit-appearance: none;
background-color: #fff;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;}

.regular-checkbox:checked {
background-color: #39c;
color: #fff !important;}

.regular-checkbox:hover {
background-color: #f0f7f9;}

.regular-checkbox:checked:after {
color: #fff;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 3px;
color: #99a1a7; }
```

So any suggestions?

Also does anyone know how to change the highlight because at the moment it seems to highlight the edges of the box at a border radius of 3px whereas the boxes I am using are 6px.

Comment: Seen can you create a jsFiddle so we can see your code in action and help?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725811/remove-css-hover-attribute-with-jquery

Comment: @ElendilTheTall The post you're linking to deals with jQuery, whereas here the OP is asking about a CSS issue.

Comment: @seangeraghty It's not clear what is the expected result. Your code doesn't seem to make any attempt to style elements who are both checked and hovered. Are you perhaps asking how to chain the pseudo selectors? Simply try `checked:hover`.

Comment: @Boaz please take a look at the JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sa9fe/

Comment: @boaz And how are you supposed to alter CSS classes without some kind of scripting?

Comment: @ElendilTheTall please take a look at the JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sa9fe/

Comment: @damienhawks http://jsfiddle.net/sa9fe/

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Class declarations can simply be overridden by another more specific declaration...

Comment: @seangeraghty Try [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/sa9fe/2/)

Comment: @seangeraghty You should also limit your posts to one question or at least have some connection between your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So just add this

```
.regular-checkbox:checked, .regular-checkbox:checked:hover {
    background-color: #39c;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

and if you want remove blue border add `outline:0;` on your `.regular-checkbox` class

http://jsfiddle.net/sa9fe/4/

Comment: Great! Works a treat!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this

```
.regular-checkbox:checked:hover {
    background-color: #39c;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sa9fe/5/

Answer (score 0):

if you are familiar with jQuery, you can define an onClick event for a particular checkbox and inside of function use `removeClass(classname)`. You can find more at [jQuery api site](http://api.jquery.com).