# Box-Shadow CSS for Bootstrap Custom Checkbox

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to remove the Shadow That occur on clicking over Checkbox. I've taken the custom Checkbox of *Bootstrap 4* and Colored the necessary things, but I'm unable to find from where the **Box-Shadow** is Showing Here's my code-

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1"><h6>Change flooring - ₹ 10</h6></label>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You means this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056163/remove-a-hover-class-from-a-checkbox-once-clicked ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ There are already several questions on SO about accessing BS4 `box-shadow` attribute, including the one commented above. This is a link to the upvoted / accepted answer to another question, which will likely help >>> https://stackoverflow.com/a/43612974/3711083

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 4: customize checkbox border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612852/bootstrap-4-customize-checkbox-border)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the style selector that sets up the 'box-shadow'

```
.custom-control-input:focus~.custom-control-label::before {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0,123,255,.25);
    }
```