# reduce <DIV> width when external page loaded in same page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Am using the following code to load external in same page,in `<div id="menu">` i have menu and when option is clicked external page will be loaded inside `<div class="page"></div>`

- menu width is 25%
- page is 70%

Now how do i change width of `<div id="menu">` to 10% when external page is loaded

**FULL CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <style>
            #menu{width:25%;background-color:beige;float: left}
            .page{width: 70%;height:200px;float: left;background-color: #99ffff}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="box">                                        
            <div id="leftmenu">
                <ul id="leftmenuidfrmslt">
                    <li><span class="flaticon-smart"></span><text>&nbsp;&nbsp;Mobile & Tablet</text>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a class="reveal" href="postpage/mobile.php">&Xi;&nbsp;Mobile Phones</a></li>
                            <li><a class="reveal" href="postpage/tablet.php">&Xi;&nbsp;Tablets</a></li>
                            <li><a class="reveal" href="postpage/mobileaccessories.php">&Xi;&nbsp;Mobile Accessories</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
</div>
        <div class="page"></div>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.reveal').on('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var link = $(this).attr('href');
                    $('.page').load(link);
                    $('#leftmenu').css('width', '70px');
                    $("#leftmenu text").hide();
                    $('#leftmenu').off("click");
                    $(this).show();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you try `$("#menu").css("width","10%");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change width using jquery css      `$('#menu').css('width', '10%');`

$(document).ready(function() {

```
        $('.reveal').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var link = $(this).attr('href');
            $('.page').load(link);
            $('#menu').css('width', '10%');
            $(this).show();
        });
```

Comment: how can i hide text inside that div alone

Comment: try this to hide text  $('#menu').css('color', 'transparent');

Comment: Everything works fine i need to disable the entire div ,Hover effect and click ,,??

Comment: $('#menu').click(function() {
    $('#menu').hide();
}); to hide div

Comment: $('#menu').unbind('click'); to disable click in the div

Comment: its not working when i click after div size is reduced sub menu opens

Comment: check question i have changed java script

Comment: $('.page').load(link);
$(this).hide();

Comment: When external page is loaded i need to disable `hover, click` function in `<div id="menu">`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725811/remove-css-hover-attribute-with-jquery

Comment: $("#menu").off("click");

Comment: check above question i have changed code, when i click sub menu  `#leftmenu` width is reduced now at the same time i need to disable `hover, click,`

Comment: would you please reproduce a fiddle link that regenerate the problem